# JS-issue "undefined query" when trying to create chrome-plugin

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, google-plugin-eclipse

I tried to make a plugin but got the error: `undefined query`. I tried to solve this issue and tested in different projects but the error persisted.

*Content.js*

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
   if (request.action === "convert") {
       document.documentElement.style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
       sendResponse({ message: "Website converted to black and white." });
   } else if (request.action === "reset") {
       document.documentElement.style.filter = "none";
       sendResponse({ message: "Website reset to original colors." });
   }
});
```

*popup.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css">
       <script src="popup.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>Black & White Converter</h1>
       <button id="convertButton">Convert</button>
       <button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
   </body>
</html>
```